# Обосновано ли здесь использование паттерна Builder

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть абстрактный класс Человек, от него наследуется класс Работник. Для класса Работник создаю свой Builder:

Пример:

```
public abstract class Human {
private long id;
private Gender gender;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

    public Human() {
    super();
}

public Human(long id, Gender gender, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.setId(id);
    this.gender = gender;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

}


public class EmployeeHuman extends Human {
private long id;
private Company company;
private Appointment appointment;

EmployeeHuman() {
    super();
}

EmployeeHuman(final EmployeeHumanBuilder employeeHumanBuilder) {
    super(employeeHumanBuilder.getId(),
          employeeHumanBuilder.getGender(),
          employeeHumanBuilder.getFirstName(),
          employeeHumanBuilder.getLastName());
    this.id = employeeHumanBuilder.getId();
    this.company = employeeHumanBuilder.getCompany();
    this.appointment = employeeHumanBuilder.getAppointment();
}

}


public class EmployeeHumanBuilder {
private long id;
private Gender gender;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Company company;
private Appointment appointment;

public EmployeeHumanBuilder id(final long id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
}

public EmployeeHumanBuilder gender(final Gender gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
    return this;
}

public EmployeeHumanBuilder firstName(final String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    return this;
}

public EmployeeHumanBuilder lastName(final String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    return this;
}

public EmployeeHumanBuilder company(final Company company) {
    this.company = company;
    return this;
}

public EmployeeHumanBuilder appointment(final Appointment appointment) {
    this.appointment = appointment;
    return this;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public Appointment getAppointment() {
    return appointment;
}

public EmployeeHuman build() {
    return new EmployeeHuman(this);
}
}
```

Вопрос: правильно ли реализован паттерн Builder? Нужен ли он здесь или это горе от ума?

Comment: вы паттерн из GoF реализуете? или какой-то другой?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да.

Comment: откройте статью и посмотрите. где у вас абстрактный builder?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, т.е для класса **Human** нужен свой абстрактный класс Builder? Нужен ли здесь вообще Builder?

Comment: GoF builder тут не нужен. А вот fluent интерфейс (builder) может быть уместен при большом количестве разных полей.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, понял

Answer (score 0):

Builder реализован неправильно. Класс EmployeeHuman не должен зависеть от Builder'а. Просто у него в конструкторе много параметров и для того, чтобы облегчить их ввод, Builder накапливает их, а потом создает объект, вызывая его конструктор с этими параметрами. Кстати, так можно легко создавать множество одинаковых (или почти одинаковых) обеъктов. Вот правильная реализация:

```java
public class EmployeeHuman extends Human {
    private Company company;
    private Appointment appointment;

    EmployeeHuman() {
        super();
    }

    EmployeeHuman(long id, Gender gender, String firstName, String lastName, Company company, Appointment appointment) {
        super(id, gender, firstName, lastName);
        this.company = company;
        this.appointment = appointment;
    }
}


public class EmployeeHumanBuilder {
    private long id;
    private Gender gender;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Company company;
    private Appointment appointment;

    public EmployeeHumanBuilder id(final long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeHumanBuilder gender(final Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeHumanBuilder firstName(final String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeHumanBuilder lastName(final String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeHumanBuilder company(final Company company) {
        this.company = company;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeHumanBuilder appointment(final Appointment appointment) {
        this.appointment = appointment;
        return this;
    }

    public EmployeeHuman build() {
        return new EmployeeHuman(id, gender, firstName, lastName, company, appointment);
    }
}
```